# AWS EC2 access file with relative path in Node app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a node (v10) app deployed and running on an EC2 instance. So I'm trying to write to a file in the assets directory within the app. I declared the path in app.js

```
app.set('assets',path.join(__dirname, 'assets'));
```

In my script, this is how I'm doing it

```
let fileName = 'data.json'
fs.writeFile('assets/'+fileName, response.Body.toString('ascii'),(err) => { if(err) console.log(err); });
```

The data.json file is in the assets directory. This works fine when I test it in my local environment. But when I test it in the deployed app, I get the following error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'assets/data.json'] {
data:    bin/www:89 -   errno: -2,
data:    bin/www:89 -   code: 'ENOENT',
data:    bin/www:89 -   syscall: 'open',
data:    bin/www:89 -   path: 'assets/data.json'
data:    bin/www:89 - }
```

Could you please help me how to access the file when deployed on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
fs.writeFile(__dirname + 'assets/'+fileName, response.Body.toString('ascii'),(err) => { if(err) console.log(err); });
```

as `__dirname` will give you current directory in which your node application is placed.

Or

```
fs.writeFile(app.get('assets')+'/'+fileName,
```

as you are setting `assets` value.

Currently, you are trying to access `/assets` as absolute path which dosen't exists in Ubuntu or any linux.

Comment: Hey. So I have the fs operation in a different script. I am importing the app module as ```const app = require('../app')```. When I use app.get('assets'), I get the error that app.get is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the variable you are setting earlier. You should be using it like this:

```
fs.writeFile(app.settings.assets + '/' + fileName, response.Body.toString('ascii'),(err) => { if(err) console.log(err); });
```

Also, it sounds like the `assets` folder doesn't actually exist yet on the EC2 instance. You may need to call `fs.mkdir(app.settings.assets)` first.

Comment: Hey. So I have the fs operation in a different script. I am exporting app module in app.js as ```module.exports = app```. I am importing app in my script as ```const app = require('../app');```. So when I try app.settings.assets, I get an error as ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'assets' of undefined```